# Problemas para convina if y for

Tags: c#, windows-forms, bucle-for, condiciones

Hola estoy comenzando con c# windows fomr y tengo un problema quiero saber si puedo al cumplirse un condicion ejecutar un for ya lo hice con un label y no funciono capaz me estoy saltando algo muy tonto pero bueno les dejo el codigo(simple) gracias.

```
       int numero = Convert.ToInt32(txtNombre.Text);
        

        if (numero == 5)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                MessageBox.Show("vota");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("no vota");
        }
```

Comment: q la condicion no se cumple

Comment: No hay ningún problema con tu código. El solo se ejecuta cómo tu le pediste. Quizá el problema esté en que `txtNombre` siempre es el mismo. Por cierto, un **Label** solo puede ser modificado desde el diseñador o por código. En cambio, un **Texbox** también puede ser modificado por el usuario.